# Visual Studio Multi-Project Templates - Add or Remove Project Links

Tags: visual-studio, wizard, solution, project-template, visual-studio-templates

I have a multi-project template that creates a solution with several default projects.

I wanted to provide some UI that would allow projects to be selected/de-selected to customize the final solution.

I have been unable to figure out where I can modify the project links using a Wizard Extension, it appears I can only change parameters

An example of my multi-project template is as follows:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="ProjectGroup">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>My Services Solution</Name>
    <Description>My Services Solution</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <RequiredFrameworkVersion>4.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
    <DefaultName>My.Services.Solution</DefaultName>
    <CreateNewFolder>false</CreateNewFolder>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$">
            Root\Root.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Client">
            Client\Client.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Web">
            Web\Web.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <SolutionFolder Name="Tests" TargetFolderName="Tests">
          <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="Test.$safeprojectname$">
            Test\Test.vstemplate
          </ProjectTemplateLink>
        </SolutionFolder>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Does anyone know a way to make (for example) the Client ProjectTemplateLink optional?

Thanks in advance